# Is Google's automatic Zip-before-download lossless?

Tags: google-drive, online-storage

Google Drive automatically compresses large files or groups of files before downloading, using the Zip file format. Zip supports both lossless and lossy compression algorithms, so my question is really about what compression algorithm Google Drive uses to zip files before download.

The reason I ask this is that, if the algorithm is lossless, then I will just download a bunch of files all at once, and then uncompress them on my local computer. However, if the compression is lossy, I will download the files one by one to avoid decreasing the file quality. I here mention my intention because I've concluded that it might help in answering the question better.

Comment: How do end-users will be able to answer a question like this? If this is something that only Googlers can answer then the question is off-topic.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for pointing that out! I didn't know such questions were off-topic. I asked because I had seen people who worked or formerly worked for Google hang around on SE and answer questions. Additionally, I initially told myself that that information might be accessible somewhere publicly, although I didn't know where, so that's another reason why I asked the question. Hopefully, Google has made this clear somewhere. If they haven't, then I suppose my question is off-topic indeed.

Comment: Googlera and people that work for other web app developers are welcome to answers questions herebut customer service, customer support, questions about internal policies and the tecnologies that make web apps work are off-topic here. This particular question looks to me to be an edge question... I'm wondering if it might be possible to analysize a downloaded zip to figured out the algorithm used to compress it.

Comment: @Rubén It certainly is possible! Thank you for the neat idea. (See my answer below.) God bless you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer:**
Zip uses lossless algorithms. I have not been able to find any reference to lossy algorithms that would be used by Zip.

Furthermore, several types of files can be uploaded into Google drive and lossy compression does only apply to specific types of files. Lossy compression does make sense for pictures, video or music, but they all have their specific parameters to describe how lossy you allow the compression to be. However, it would not make sense for texts, databases, applications, configuration files and all proprietary file formats which are not necessarily supported by Google. For those files, lossy compression would irreparably damage the content...

Google Photos has a different behaviour, but you then have some control on how your files are handled.

**Sources:**

1. Wikipedia page of Zip: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format), *"ZIP is an archive file format that supports lossless data compression."*
2. From Quora: https://www.quora.com/Are-files-uploaded-to-Google-Drive-compressed-or-uploaded-as-original-quality-and-size-In-other-words-is-anything-changed-when-uploading (this questions covers the upload process, so you will have to read several posts to come to the conclusion that zip files downloaded from Google Drive are also lossless)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you for those useful insights. PDFs, (I don't know if you consider those "text") are lossily compressible: https://www.investintech.com/resources/blog/archives/6602-how-to-compress-pdf.html However, as you say, Google might not have implemented an algorithm for the lossy compression of such file types, as there are many, although PDFs are quite popular. Thank you again for your useful and complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer:

The algorithm that Google Drive uses to compress large files or groups of files before downloading is lossless. Specifically, the algorithm used is called "[DEFLATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflate)", and is a pretty popular algorithm for lossless compression. It uses a combination of the [LZ77](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78) and [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) algorithms. (Wikipedia, 2022)

### Method:

A simple way to verify that this is true is by running the following command in the terminal, after having downloaded an automatically zipped file from Google Drive: (SE, 2018)

```
7z l -slt file-downloaded-from-google-drive.zip | grep -e '^---' -e '^Path =' -e '^Method ='
```

This will list all the files in the compressed folder or archive, as well as the method of compression for each. In the case of a Google Drive Zip file, all the compressed files contained within it will be listed as having been compressed using the "Deflate" algorithm, which is better known in its stylised form, "DEFLATE".

### Sources:

1. SE Contributors. (2018, February 22). *How to determine compression method of a ZIP/RAR file*. Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896487/how-to-determine-compression-method-of-a-zip-rar-file
   Answer by “palswim” (12k rep.)
2. Wikipedia Contributors. (2022, November 4). *DEFLATE*. Wikipedia; Wikimedia Foundation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE